# Redirect user to original url after login in asp net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to redirect original page after login

```
 public ActionResult UnAuthorize(string ReturnUrl)
            {
                return Redirect("/Account/SignIn?ReturnUrl=" + ReturnUrl);
            }
```

url : http://localhost:18908/Account/SignIn?ReturnUrl=/Customer/Index

```
 public JsonResult SignIn(SignInModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            try
            {
  return Redirect(returnUrl);

               }
```

But returnUrl return value of null or empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class SignInModel
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
         public ActionResult UnAuthorize(string ReturnUrl)
         {
              return Redirect("/Account/SignIn?ReturnUrl=" + ReturnUrl);
          }

       [HttpGet]
       public ActionResult SignIn(string returnUrl)
       {
           ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
           return View();
       }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SignIn(SignInModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**SignIn view**

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.SignInModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
}

<h2>View</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SignInModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**Customer Index View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customers";
}

    <h2>Customer</h2>
```

Focus on **HttpGet SingIn action** and **SignIn view**.

try: http://localhost:18908/Account/UnAuthorize?ReturnUrl=/Customer/Index